# Creating a prolog rule with count

Tags: count, prolog, rule

```
mother(X, Y):- child(Y, X), female(X).
```

How would I have code to find out whether or not `X` is the mother of at least 3 children? Would I have to use some sort of aggregate to see how many times `child(Y,X)` would happen?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you want but I suppose that the following example could help

```
motherOf3OrMore(X) :-
  female(X),
  findall(Y, child(Y, X), L),
  length(L, N),
  N >= 3.
```

If the minimum number of childs isn't a fixed number (3) you can pass it as a parameter as follows

```
motherOfMore(X, N) :-
  female(X),
  findall(Y, child(Y, X), L),
  length(L, M),
  M >= N.
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question